# How can I tokenize python source code that has a syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax-error, tokenize

I'm trying to **tokenize python source code with syntax errors** to then give it as input into a statistical model (eg. a Recurring Neural Net).

However the built in `tokenizer.py` yields `ErrorToken` for the python code with syntax error.

This is the function I'm using:

```py
def to_token_list(s: str) -> List:
    tokens = []  # list of tokens extracted from source code.

    g = tokenize.tokenize(BytesIO(s.encode("utf-8")).readline)

    for t in g:
        tokens.append(t)

    return tokens
```

Here is an example input - it is missing a closing bracket (objects are masked as `ID`):

```py
syntax_error_source_code = "\ndef ID ID ):\n    if ID .ID :\n        ID .ID .ID ()\n"
to_token_list(syntax_error_source_code)
```

Error:

```py
Exception has occurred: TokenError
('EOF in multi-line statement', (5, 0))
```

I could solve this error by wrapping the function in `try-except` but it won't solve it for errors that are intermediary as the next example.

Another example that fails the `try-except`:

```py
syntax_error_source_code = '\ndef ID ():\n/    for ID ,ID in ID :\n        pass \n    for ID ,ID in ID :\n        pass \n'
to_token_list(syntax_error_source_code)
```

Error:

```py
Exception has occurred: IndentationError
unindent does not match any outer indentation level (<tokenize>, line 5)
```

I have found this discussion on the issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue12675

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: ```  g = tokenize.tokenize(BytesIO(s.encode("utf-8")).readline)``` this works?  isn't ```readline``` a function? so should be called ```.readline())``` or did I miss something?

Comment: The function itself is correct, this is the pattern recommended in the documentation. If I give it syntactically correct source code, eg.: "\ndef ID ID ():\n    if ID .ID :\n        ID .ID .ID ()\n" then it doesn't fail.

Comment: Python's token structure is only defined for inputs with matching parentheses and sufficiently-consistent indentation - the rules for whether or not to generate NEWLINE tokens depend on processing matching parentheses, and the rules for generating INDENT and DEDENT tokens depend on dedents matching indentation levels.

Comment: Given that your input doesn't actually have a well-defined token structure, what sort of output are you looking for?

Comment: (And what kind of output would you want for inputs like `a $ b`, where `$` doesn't form any sort of valid Python token? Or inputs with, say, unclosed string literals?)

Comment: I understand your point and it's clear that this is good, intended behaviour by the library. What I could work with is it tokenizing as best as it could -- eg.: giving an errortoken for unknown tokens and skipping indentation and EOF errors.

Comment: Maybe the question is: I can't find a library that builds on top of tokenize.py to handle such a conversion. Does anybody know of such?

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is? Do you need just string tokens of whatever you pass or knowing about syntax errors is important? Because you can simply use string.split or any other tokenizer, like nltk if you just want tokens

Comment: Ideally I would get a list of tokens that specify the type of each keyword. For correct code I get ``[62, 61, 1, 1, 1, 54, 54, 54, 4, 5, 1, 1, 54, 1, 54, 4, 5, 1, 54, 1, 54, 1, 54, 54, 4, 6, 6, 0]``; where eg.: ``62 = ENCODING``. I might be asking for an impossible task, as a code with a syntax error yields undefined tokenization.

Comment: My goal is to feed the wrong python code into a Deep Neural Net and predict the location of the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I have found a solution to this problem from someone going through the same course](https://github.com/ValeKnappich/CodeLSTM/blob/883d81c418a5a8a76b3bdce86b2630f88b1052a1/milestone2/data.py)

Below is the relevant part.

**The tokenizer is:**

```py
import tokenize
import io

def tokenizer(
        s: str, id: int, error_dict: dict
    ) -> List[tokenize.TokenInfo]:
    
    fp = io.StringIO(s)
    filter_types = [tokenize.ENCODING, tokenize.ENDMARKER, tokenize.ERRORTOKEN]
    tokens = []
    token_gen = tokenize.generate_tokens(fp.readline)
    while True:
        try:
            token = next(token_gen)
            if token.string and token.type not in filter_types:
                tokens.append(token)
        except tokenize.TokenError:
            error_dict["TokenError"].append(id)
            break
        except StopIteration:
            break
        except IndentationError:
            error_dict["IndentationError"].append(id)
            continue
    return tokens
```

**Some clarification:**

- `error_dict` is a dictionary of errors that might pop up, eg.: `{"TokenError": [], "IndentationError": []}`
- `s` is the source_code in string format that you want to tokenize
- `id` is the id of the source_code in a larger database, if you are tokenizing multiple snippets/files.